# Sencha ExtJS why option returns null?

Tags: extjs

I can not find reason why "option" is returns "null".

Here is a fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3epo

Answer (score 0):

That's because you did not define the `getOption()` method

You can use this notation, in order to retrieve what you are looking for:

```
console.log('FIELD OPTION:', store.getAt(0).get('option'));
```